# Не парсится дата с сокращенными названиями месяцев

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Имеются даты такого формата: 14.апр.13.
Для парсинга использую такой формат:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d.MMM.yy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Список всех месяцев: янв, фев, мар, апр, май, июн, июл, авг, сен, окт, ноя, дек. Из этого списка не парсятся янв, апр, авг, окт, дек. Выдает ошибку `Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14.апр.13"`
В чем проблема и как это можно решить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2009224/11752991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
String date = "14.апр.13";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.MMM.yy", Locale.forLanguageTag("ru"));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(date, formatter));
```

Я специально заменил локацию на русскую, я не знаю, что у вас по дефолту на вашем компьютере (у меня с дефолтной тоже работает, а вы проверяйте и решайте сами с учетом поддержки мультиязычности и прочих факторов).

Comment: Спасибо, так работает теперь

Comment: @tdutyui не за что, удачи